# How to get max valued xref's 'rid' except from particular section

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest for how get the maximum 'rid' value from all xrefs except from the 'Online' sections. By identify the max valued 'rid', then need to insert the attribute to those references which are higher to maximum value. Please see required result text.

**XML:**

```
<article>
<body>
    <sec><title>Sections</title>
    <p>The test <xref rid="b1">1</xref>, <xref rid="b2">2</xref>, <xref rid="b3 b4 b5">3-5</xref></p></sec>
    <sec><title>Online</title><!--This section's xrefs no need to consider-->
        <p>The test <xref rid="b6">6</xref></p>
        <sec><title>Other</title>
            <p><xref rid="b1">1</xref>, <xref rid="b7 b8">7-8</xref></p>
        </sec>
    </sec><!--This section's xrefs no need to consider-->
    <sec>
        <p>Final test test</p>
        <sec><title>Third title</title><p>Last text</p></sec>
    </sec>
</body>
<bm>
    <ref id="b1">The ref01</ref>
    <ref id="b2">The ref02</ref>
    <ref id="b3">The ref03</ref>
    <ref id="b4">The ref04</ref>
    <ref id="b5">The ref05</ref>
    <ref id="b6">The ref06</ref>
    <ref id="b7">The ref07</ref>
    <ref id="b8">The ref08</ref>
</bm>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="var1"><!--Variable to get the all 'rid's except sec/title contains 'Online' -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//xref[not(. is ancestor::sec[title[contains(., 'Online')]]/descendant-or-self)]/@rid">
    <!--xsl:for-each select="//xref/@rid[not(contains(ancestor::sec/title, 'Online'))]"--><!--for this xpath, error is : "XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument" -->
    <!--xsl:for-each select="//xref/@rid[not(contains(ancestor::sec[1]/title, 'Online')) and not(contains(ancestor::sec[2]/title, 'Online'))]"--><!--for this xpath we are getting the required result, but there may be several nesting of 'sec's -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., ' ')">
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' ')">
                    <a><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><a><xsl:value-of select="."/></a></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="varMax1">
    <xsl:for-each select="$var1/a">
        <xsl:sort select="substring-after(., 'b')" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <a><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="varMax"><!--Variable to get max valued RID -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($varMax1/a[1], 'b')"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref">
    <xsl:variable name="varID"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@id, 'b')"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($varMax) lt number($varID)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="MoveRef">yes</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required result:**

```
<article>
<body>
    <sec><title>Sections</title>
    <p>The test <xref rid="b1">1</xref>, <xref rid="b2">2</xref>, <xref rid="b3 b4 b5">3-5</xref></p></sec>
    <sec><title>Online</title><!--This section's xrefs no need to consider-->
        <p>The test <xref rid="b6">6</xref></p>
        <sec><title>Other</title>
            <p><xref rid="b1">1</xref>, <xref rid="b7">7</xref>, <xref rid="b8">8</xref></p>
        </sec>
    </sec><!--This section's xrefs no need to consider-->
    <sec>
        <p>Final test test</p>
        <sec><title>Third title</title><p>Last text</p></sec>
    </sec>
</body>
<bm>
    <ref id="b1">The ref01</ref>
    <ref id="b2">The ref02</ref>
    <ref id="b3">The ref03</ref>
    <ref id="b4">The ref04</ref>
    <ref id="b5">The ref05</ref>
    <ref id="b6" MoveRef="yes">The ref06</ref>
    <ref id="b7" MoveRef="yes">The ref07</ref>
    <ref id="b8" MoveRef="yes">The ref08</ref>
</bm>
</article>
```

Here consider number 5 for 'b5' rid, 6 for 'b6'.... (Because alphanumeric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can take a different approach rather than trying to find the maximum `rid` attribute that is not in an "online" section. Not least because it is not entirely clear what the maximum is when you are dealing with an alphanumeric string.

Instead, you could define a key to look up elements in the "online" section by their name

```
<xsl:key name="online" match="sec[title = 'Online']//*" use="name()" />
```

And then, another key, to look up the `xref` elements that occur in other sections

```
<xsl:key name="other" match="xref[not(ancestor::sec/title = 'Online')]" use="name()" />
```

Then, you can write a template to math the `ref` elements, and use an `xsl:if` to determine whether to add `MoveRef` attribute to it:

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
<xsl:if test="key('online', 'xref')[tokenize(@rid, ' ')[. = $id]] and not(key('other', 'xref')[tokenize(@rid, ' ')[. = $id]])">
```

Try this much shorter XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="online" match="sec[title = 'Online']//*" use="name()" />
    <xsl:key name="other" match="xref[not(ancestor::sec/title = 'Online')]" use="name()" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref">
        <ref>
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
            <xsl:if test="key('online', 'xref')[tokenize(@rid, ' ')[. = $id]] and not(key('other', 'xref')[tokenize(@rid, ' ')[. = $id]])">
                <xsl:attribute name="MoveRef" select="'Yes'" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ref>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can actually amend the `ref` template to put the condition in the template match, if you wanted...

```
<xsl:template match="ref[key('online', 'xref')[tokenize(@rid, ' ')[. = current()/@id]] and not(key('other', 'xref')[tokenize(@rid, ' ')[. = current()/@id]])]">
    <ref MoveRef="Yes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ref>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but if range type like <xref rid="b7 b8">7-8</xref>, then we are not getting the required result.

Comment: @RudramuniTP - I have amended my answer to cope with this situation. It might be worth amending your question to show an example of `<xref rid="b7 b8">` in your XML. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your perfect suggestion, working perfectly as required. Plus one...